# Flask-SQLAlchemy Query Returns the Database Class and the Data

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

When I query my Database using .first() the Database returns a class

```
idtest = AddCompanyData.query.order_by(AddCompanyData.company_guid.desc()).first()
```

returns: `<AddCompanyData 2>`

The number "2" is correct but why won't it return just the number.

Comment: I figured out the issue. Basically, you have to specify the column in your output. Example: idtest.company_guid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because SQLAlchemy is usually used as an [ORM (object-relational mapper)](https://www.fullstackpython.com/object-relational-mappers-orms.html). That means rows in tables are represented as objects in Python. If you query your database, SQLAlchemy will give you the result as such an object. If you want to access the value of a specific property/column, you can use the `.` operator.
In your example e.g.

```
idtest.id
```

will give you the value of the `id` attribute/column.